# How to rowspan all th/td in 2 rows?

Tags: html, css

[Sample fail lol](http://jsfiddle.net/GRPzU/)

But what I want is to have the first `thead tr` to span across the next `tr` which in the example was empty.
Any ideas?

I basically want to have a header row which is **twice** the height(dynamic) of a normal row.

Comment: define "height of normal row"

Comment: When you say you want each column of a row to span across the respective column of next row means, you actually mean you need ONLY one row.. Could someone help what exactly I am not interpreting correctly here? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correctly using rowspan="2"
Check little modification of you code:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">header 1</th>
        <th rowspan="2">header 2</th>
        <th rowspan="2">header 3</th>
        <th>header 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>header 5</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>enter code here
</tbody>
```

In you example the first `<tr>` doesn't have any height, so th rowspan has no visible effect...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add borderspacing='0' to the table like this

```
<table cellspacing='0'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2">header 1</th>
            <th rowspan="2">header 2</th>
            <th rowspan="2">header 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And css:

```
th, td {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/GRPzU/5/